# Developing .net MVC3 application for caching using AppFabric 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am using windows server AppFabric 1.1 and want to use caching in asp.net MVC3 application. How can I start? I tried many of the online samples and it gave run time errors. Please help me with Sample applications or  tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AppFabric Caching in three ways in asp.net MVC 3 :

**As a session state provider**

This provider enables you to store your session state in a distributed cache rather than in-memory or in a SQL Server database. MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361709%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

**As an output provider**
AppFabric provider plugs into the new output cache provider extensibility point that was introduced in ASP.NET 4. MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361707%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

**As a distributed data cache**
Create code that puts, retrieves, and removes your objects from the cache. Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric_Caching). Be sure to [install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334245%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) AppFabric correctly and that it's running.

At the end, what are your *run time errors* ?

Comment: if I want to use appfabric as an output cache provider, do I require any coding for that? will it still be available in distributed environment?